# std::getline returning the wrong size

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, vector, getline

1. something wrong with getline(), taking the words in correct but still the value of size remains 26.
2. I tried printing each time it takes in a character and all of them do print so itis taking in strings correctly, but not storing them?
3. I have attached the code below to refer
4. Ask me for the whole project if you need to refer what is going wrong if someplace else.

   ```
   void TldPart::PreloadTLDs()
   {
       ifstream in(TLD_TEST_FILE);

       if(in)
       {
           string tld;
           for(int i =0; !in.eof(); i++)
           {
               getline(in,tld);

               String myString = tld.c_str();

               //cout << myString.GetLength() << endl;

               for(int j=0; j<myString.GetLength();j++)
               {
                   myString[j]=tolower(myString[j]);
               }

               //cout << myString << endl;
               ValidTLDs.insert(pair<String,int>(myString,i));
               //ValidTLDs[myString] = true; //if the map was bool
           }
           in.close();
           cout << ValidTLDs.size(); //Printing the size //prints 26
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What type is `ValidTLDs`?

Comment: It is the map in which I'm storing the String

Comment: Why are you using a map if you're _forcing_ each item to be unique with `i`? How are you going to look up these items in the map given that the pair has an arbitrary `i`?

Comment: Never mind, scratch that last comment.

Comment: I'm assuming the strings are unique, yes?

Comment: Actually, why are you using two different string types?

Comment: Is it possible the strings you are inserting to the map are single character strings between a and z? That would explain why you get 26 unique keys.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem but `in.eof()` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't tell you if you've reached the eof. It tells you that you tried to read past the eof, which means that you wind up processing the last line twice. `getline()` is convertible to `bool` and will be false when you reach the eof. Use `for (int j = 0; getline(in, tld); ++j)` instead.

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm trying to use my own string class while just using the predefined class for getline()

Comment: @Eran That actually might be the problem, but when I'm just printing the strings after getline, it prints everything perfectly and I checked while debugging that it was storing all characters. Not just unique between a to z